# Getting TeamCity to work with ClearCase

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity, clearcase

I'm trying to set up TeamCity (latest version -- 6.0.3) to play nicely with a ClearCase view.

I've found several resources online, some on this site, but mostly outdated.

I am not sure whether configuring TeamCity with ClearCase is possible.

Few questions i have:

1. Should I be using a Dynamic View or Snapshot view?
2. Any special configurations needed to be done?
3. Is there any tutorial on how to set this up?

All my efforts so far have not succeeded, receiving all sorts of errors...

Please help me in setting this up.

BTW: if there is another FREE alternative for TeamCity that will integrate well with ClearCase, it is also a valid option.

Comment: Ive successfully used Cruise Control .net with Clearcase (oh so slow). I used snapshot views. Not as pretty but the core build was exactly the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only setup I saw working with ClearCase and TeamCity is by using the TCC (TeamCity ClearCase plugin) developed by my colleague [Gilles Philippart](https://stackoverflow.com/users/50114/gilles-philippart):

**[TCC GitHub repo](https://github.com/gphilipp/TCCC/commits/master)**: as illustrated by this [recent commit](https://github.com/gphilipp/TCCC/commit/86993295f26bdaec8bdbeba923ce5653bdcb9d04), it is based on a snapshot view.
I don't have many details on the setup, but it [works well with a TeamCity6.x](https://github.com/gphilipp/TCCC/commit/518b5e7451356abc1526531b61e6c748828bd049).

Comment: Thanks, i will check it out. Is there any other CI product that allows easier integration with CC?

Comment: @liortal: we had some success with Jenkins and some dynamic views (http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Clearcase+Plugin), but for serious CI, after study (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3597747/can-we-finally-move-to-dvcs-in-corporate-software-is-svn-still-a-must-have-for/3597851#3597851), we moved to Git (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5159943/value-of-using-git-with-clearcase-accurev-or-perforce/5160225#5160225): getting what has changed is infinity quicker with Git, and it comes a top-notch integration

Comment: @liortal: we had some success with Jenkins and some dynamic views (wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Clearcase+Plugin), but for serious CI, after study (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3597851), we moved to Git (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5160225 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5685757): getting what has changed is infinity quicker with Git, and it comes a top-notch integration